# Handshake error in flutter while loading image via cached_image_network

Tags: flutter, cachemanager

CacheManager: Failed to download file from https://gorealestates.com/storage/products/thumb/Property_119989_72753174907.png with error:
I/flutter (19986): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
I/flutter (19986):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:393))
I/flutter (19986): CacheManager: Failed to download file from https://gorealestates.com/storage/products/thumb/1661318454_plots-in-siktaur-gorakhpur.jpg with error:
I/flutter (19986): HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
I/flutter (19986):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: Hostname mismatch(handshake.cc:393))

Comment: try with images from any different website and see if same error appears

Comment: You are right sir , it is working fine for other website

Answer (score 0):

These are related to image host server not client.

Comment: Image are loading well well full url is viewed throw browser

Comment: when you access image from chrome from address bar there is no issue, but when you try to access image from diffrent origin like a website with diffrent url or android app some server raises cors issue with that , so it is because of server host CORS settings or security settings,

Comment: it was working fine past night , how can i solve this , Sir.